# Implementing locks and blocking threads

Tags: synchronization, operating-system, thread-safety, locking, block

If a thread tries to acquire a lock and it's taken, it should go to sleep and stay asleep until lock released. If a thread releases a lock (and it's taken by the thread that created it), it should wake up thread(s).

My question is, does it make a difference if we wake up all threads on lock address vs. a single thread on lock address (after lock release)? And if we were to wake up a single thread, which one does it make sense to wake, the first to get put to sleep on lock address?

I can see some advantage of waking up one thread, in that if we wake up all, n-1 can potentially go back to sleep. But I don't know if there are disadvantages to waking up a single thread.

Comment: If it's a lock (mutex, critical section), what could be the point of waking more than one thread waiting for it? Why "they *can potentially* go back to sleep", when it seems like the only possible thing to happen?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're confusing windows locks (mutex, critical sections) with .Net monitors (which in C# can use the keyword lock as syntax sugar for Enter/Exit a block.)

Windows mutexes and critical sections can only be entered and exited, i.e. there is only one queue associated with them. All threads in the queue wait for the lock to be released and when that happens the next thread on the queue takes control of the lock and starts running. All this happens automatically. The thread currently holding the lock has no part in this, it cannot choose to wake one or more of the other threads waiting for the lock to be released.

.Net's Monitor has two queues: a ready queue and a wait queue.

The ready queue behaves exactly like a Win32 Mutex or Critical Section queue and is controlled using the Enter/Leave methods.

The wait queue is a separate queue controlled using the Wait/Pulse/PulseAll methods. These methods can only be called by the thread holding the Monitor. When a thread calls Wait it releases the Monitor and enters the wait queue. A different thread can then call either Pulse to move one thread or Pulse All to move all threads from the wait to the ready queue (remember the thread calling Pulse/PulseAll holds the Monitor.)

From a computer science point of view the Monitor is the single primitive needed synchronize threads (semaphores, events, mutexes, barriers, etc. can all be implemented with Monitors), from a practical point of view Monitors are useful as mutexes and for situations when actions need to be performed by two threads in lock-step. Most of the time however the code is more readable when using events.

Further reading:

[Wikipedia page about Monitors for the historic/computer science aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29)

[MSDN Monitor class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx)

Comment: As the OP doesn't mention .Net anywhere, i wonder why you talk right from the beginning about .Net monitors. It would be a pity if OP gets confused that monitor is something specific to .Net, while it's a generic concept, which you otherwise explain quite nicely.

Comment: @Pavel you may be right. It just seemed to me like the likeliest mistake given the question. .Net Monitors are the only popular synchronization primitive using the "lock" keyword and which can wake other threads. I may edit the answer to make it clear Monitor is a generic concept not specifically tied to .Net.